# Does the rank of a subfunctor not exceed the rank of a functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

It is known that Vopenka's principle is equivalent to the statement “a subfunctor of a accessible functor is accessible” (Adámek and Rosický, Cor 6.31 in *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories*). Under this assumption, is it true that the rank of a subfunctor does not exceed the rank of a functor? (ranks/regular cardinals are considered infinite by definition)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rank of a functor can be exceeded by the rank of a subfunctor.

For example, let $Ab$ be the category of abelian groups. Let $Id : Ab \to Ab$ be the identity functor. Let $Tor: Ab \to Ab$ be the subfunctor which picks out the torsion elements. Then $Id$ is $\emptyset$-accessible, but $Tor$ is only $\aleph_0$-accessible.

Or, let $R$ be a non-Noetherian ring, let $M$ be a module which is finitely presentable, and let $N$ be a quotient of $M$ which is not finitely presentable. For example, we could take $M = R$ and $N = R/I$ where $I$ is a non-finitely-generated ideal; then $N$ will generally not be finitely presentable. In more particular, I think we can take $R = k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ to be a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables and $M = R$, $N = k = R / (x_1,x_2,\dots)$. Then $Hom(N,-) \subset Hom(M,-) : Mod_R \to Ab$ is a subfunctor of an $\aleph_0$-accessible functor which is not $\aleph_0$-accessible.

Comment: Thank you! While thinking about this question, I didn't think of finite cardinals as regular ones. It seems to me a really interesting question in the case where we, by definition, consider that ranks/regular cardinals are infinite (if finite cardinals are the only exception in this matter, then we should know that). I'll add this clarification to the question.